# How to create a spatial index in a GeoPackage with GeoTools?

Tags: geotools, geopackage, spatial-index

I want to write a GeoPackage file with GeoTools and **create a spatial index** in the end. After consulting the [documentation](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/geopackage.html) and also the [implementation](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/24.x/modules/plugin/geopkg/src/main/java/org/geotools/geopkg/GeoPackage.java) I still can not figure out a way to do this **using the `DataStore`-based high-level API**.

My questions are:

1. is there a way to write an rtree-based spatial index with the `DataStore` API? I figure `JDBCDataStore.createIndex` is not what we want. See `createIndexHighLevelApi` in the code below.
2. Assuming the index can only be created using the low-level API I tried to create the index after populating the GeoPackage with the high-level API. But this didn't work either as can be seen in `createSpatialIndexLowLevelApiOnExistingGpkg` below. What am I missing here?

   - java.sql.BatchUpdateException: batch entry 1: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: ST_MinX)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.data.collection.ListFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureStore;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.geopkg.FeatureEntry;
import org.geotools.geopkg.GeoPackage;
import org.geotools.geopkg.GeoPkgDataStoreFactory;
import org.geotools.jdbc.Index;
import org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore;
import org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStoreFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

public class GpkgSpatialIndexTest {

    private static final String GEOMETRY_COLUMN = "geom";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        SimpleFeatureType featureType = createType();
        SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = createFeatureCollection(featureType, 100);

        writeFeaturesAndCreateIndexWithLowLevelApi(featureCollection);
        writeFeaturesAndCreateIndexWithDataStoreApi(featureType, featureCollection);
    }

    private static void writeFeaturesAndCreateIndexWithLowLevelApi(SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection)
            throws IOException {
        File file = File.createTempFile("low_level_api", ".gpkg");
        GeoPackage geopkg = new GeoPackage(file);
        geopkg.init();

        FeatureEntry entry = new FeatureEntry();
        entry.setDescription("Cities of the world");
        geopkg.add(entry, featureCollection);
        geopkg.createSpatialIndex(entry);
    }

    public static void writeFeaturesAndCreateIndexWithDataStoreApi(SimpleFeatureType featureType,
            SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.key, GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.sample);
        Path path = Files.createTempFile("datastore_api", ".gpkg");
        map.put(GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, path.toString());
        map.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.BATCH_INSERT_SIZE.key, 50);

        DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
        dataStore.createSchema(featureType);
        SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) dataStore.getFeatureSource(featureType.getTypeName());
        featureStore.addFeatures(DataUtilities.collection(featureCollection));

        // first try. but that's not what we want - we want an rtree index!
        // also it fails:
        // org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE] A UNIQUE constraint
        // failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: layerName.geom)
        try {
            createIndexHighLevelApi(dataStore, featureType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dataStore.dispose();

        // 2nd try. let's use the low level api after the datastore
        // fails as well:
        // Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException:
        // java.sql.BatchUpdateException: batch entry 1: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or
        // missing database (no such function: ST_MinX)
        createSpatialIndexLowLevelApiOnExistingGpkg(path.toFile(), featureType.getTypeName());
    }

    private static void createIndexHighLevelApi(DataStore dataStore, SimpleFeatureType featureType) throws IOException {
        if (dataStore instanceof JDBCDataStore) {
            String layerName = featureType.getTypeName();
            ((JDBCDataStore) dataStore).createIndex(new Index(layerName,
                    Joiner.on("_").join(layerName, GEOMETRY_COLUMN, "idx"), true, GEOMETRY_COLUMN));
        }
    }

    private static void createSpatialIndexLowLevelApiOnExistingGpkg(File file, String layerName) throws IOException {
        GeoPackage gpkg = new GeoPackage(file);
        gpkg.init();
        FeatureEntry layer = gpkg.feature(layerName);
        if (layer != null) {
            // force lazy initialization of dataStore, otherwise we get a
            // NullPointerException in the next step
            gpkg.writer(layer, true, null, null);
            gpkg.createSpatialIndex(layer);
        }
        gpkg.close();
    }

    private static SimpleFeatureType createType() {
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        String layerName = "layerName";
        builder.setName(layerName);
        builder.setSRS("EPSG:4326");
        builder.add(GEOMETRY_COLUMN, LineString.class);
        builder.add("id", Integer.class);
        return builder.buildFeatureType();
    }

    private static SimpleFeatureCollection createFeatureCollection(SimpleFeatureType featureType, int count) {
        GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
        Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(16, 48), new Coordinate(14, 48) };
        LineString lineString = gf.createLineString(coordinates);
        List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Object[] attributes = new Object[] { lineString, i };
            SimpleFeature feature = SimpleFeatureBuilder.build(featureType, attributes, null);
            features.add(feature);
        }
        return new ListFeatureCollection(featureType, features);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the [unit test](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/dfc6dc028ef82556b91c8e505d2a3a15b2c77430/modules/plugin/geopkg/src/test/java/org/geotools/geopkg/GeoPackageTest.java#L572):

```
    FeatureEntry entry = new FeatureEntry();
    entry.setBounds(coll.getBounds());
    geopkg.create(entry, shp.getSchema());

    // write some features before and some after
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator it = coll.features()) {

        // some features
        try (Transaction tx = new DefaultTransaction();
                SimpleFeatureWriter w = geopkg.writer(entry, true, null, tx)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                SimpleFeature f = it.next();
                SimpleFeature g = w.next();
                for (PropertyDescriptor pd : coll.getSchema().getDescriptors()) {
                    String name = pd.getName().getLocalPart();
                    g.setAttribute(name, f.getAttribute(name));
                }

                w.write();
            }
            tx.commit();
        }

        // create spatial index
        geopkg.createSpatialIndex(entry);

        // the rest of features
        try (Transaction tx = new DefaultTransaction();
                SimpleFeatureWriter w = geopkg.writer(entry, true, null, tx)) {
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature f = it.next();
                SimpleFeature g = w.next();
                for (PropertyDescriptor pd : coll.getSchema().getDescriptors()) {
                    String name = pd.getName().getLocalPart();
                    g.setAttribute(name, f.getAttribute(name));
                }

                w.write();
            }
            tx.commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The unit test does not provide much more detail imho. I managed to create a Geopackage with the low-level API which is used there. What I could not achieve was to create an index using the DataStore API. So I figure it's simply not possible?

Comment: Not all DataStore's have indexes so I would expect to need to use a datastore specific method